# Prometheus recording rule example

Tags: prometheus

I don't understand the [recording rule example](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/rules/#examples)

> Aggregating up requests per second that has a path label:
>
> - record: instance_path:requests:rate5m   expr: rate(requests_total{job="myjob"}[5m])
> - record: path:requests:rate5m   expr: sum without (instance)(instance_path:requests:rate5m{job="myjob"})

What does "path label" mean here?

Where is "path label" used in the example?

Answer (score 1):

The missing part here is an example of the time series that is used for recording rule. I guess that time series has `__name__=requests_total` and it has labels: `job`, `instance`, `path`(e.g.`/foo/bar/`), `method`(e.g.`GET`)... So when you define

```
- record: instance_path:requests:rate5m
expr: rate(requests_total{job="myjob"}[5m])
```

you are creating new time series with `__name__=instance_path:requests:rate5m`, that has the same labels: `job`, `instance`, `path`...

and when you do:

```
- record: path:requests:rate5m
expr: sum without (instance)(instance_path:requests:rate5m{job="myjob"})
```

you are using the previously created time series with `__name__=instance_path:requests:rate5m` to create new time series with `__name__=path:requests:rate5m` where data points are aggregated with `instance` label removed. Label `path` is still kept.

Comment: You understood it much better than I did. I think the maintainers would accept a PR which updates the docs to be easier to understand. Maybe you have some time for this during the next days?